# Outlook 2016 always crashes upon startup

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, crash, dll

My installation of Outlook 2016 always crashes upon startup. Always. I tried an upgrade from 2013 as well as a fresh install. I *even* tried completely reformating my Windown 7 x64 machine and installing Outlook 2016 all over again. But, I always receive the same error.

These are the problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: OUTLOOK.EXE
  Application Version:  16.0.4266.1003
  Application Timestamp:    55ceb248
  Fault Module Name:    AppVIsvSubsystems32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.0.10331.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   55843043
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0008a0ac
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
  skulcid:  1033
Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I tried reading up on the dll file which is a fault module and ALL lead to the same answer that it is related to Microsoft Virtualization engine error and whatever they suggest, nothing is helping out.

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration for office apps ?

Comment: report it to Microsoft support. this is an access violation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) in the Microsoft App-V components.

Comment: Having the same problem.  All the other apps are fine.  But Outlook crashes each time.. no matter how I try to start it.

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have?

Comment: @LeeFuller - All other apps apart from Outlook run fine.

Comment: @QMord - Core i5 4300U

Comment: Core i7.  Microsoft spent 4 hours on my machine and could not solve it, and offered no explanation.

Comment: @LeeFuller - Lol. I'm trying to raise a service request since a week. They cannot generate a simple contract ID for my MSDN sub.

Comment: THE SOLUTION: Disable McAfee Host IPS in Quick Settings or add an exception for Outlook.exe in McAfee. Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/outlook-2016-crashes-when-launch/a4a9ed10-ce64-48c2-ba50-bf785e7b9758?page=2 (I don't have enough reputation to officially answer the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THE SOLUTION: Disable McAfee Host IPS in Quick Settings or add an exception for Outlook.exe in McAfee. Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/outlook-2016-crashes-when-launch/a4a9ed10-ce64-48c2-ba50-bf785e7b9758?page=2

This definitely worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue - however, safe mode works for me.

The hardware acceleration seems not to have to do with anything.

Outlook 2016 (and the rest of the office 2016 suite via Office 365) worked well for me until the latest updates installed.

Update:

> Description
>   Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.4229.1024, time stamp: 0x55f00f16
>   Faulting module name: mso99Lwin32client.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x55f01137
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x000000000040adac
>   Faulting process id: 0x177c
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d0fec1a114c05c
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso99Lwin32client.dll
>   Report Id: dc31ef7a-6ac9-11e5-831e-ed6dbe86aa07
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Here there DavidPostill - I know this. Unfortunately, I could not comment because my lack of reputaition...

Comment: Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)